# iPad Navigation Controller landscape issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, landscape

I am changing my application to universal and want all the views of the iPad to be in landscape mode.
My First view is a UIViewController which was added to the window using:

```
[window addSubview:mainController.view];
```

Using this view, you can select a button and a navigation controller appears. The navigation controller is added as follows:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

The main view is viewed in landscape mode correctly. However, when I add the navigation controller it is added in portrait mode (IPad is still in landscape, but the navigation controller is flipped).
I changed the shouldAutorotate methods to support landscapeLeft while using iPad, changed the iPad IB tableView to be in landscape mode, changed the plist file to be in landscape as well. Did I miss something that causes it to be added in portrait?

Thanks in Advance,

Sami

Comment: Did you tried by removing mainController before adding navigationCont? **I observed that on window only one view at a time work correctly.**

Comment: Just Tried it and It worked. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but iPad apps (universal and non-universal) need to support ALL orientations. If not Apple will reject you app (unless it is a game which obviously can't be played portrait and landscape).

Comment: @kmcgrady - That's not true, I have recently submitted a universal app where the iPad version presents only in landscape, and iPhone version only in Portrait.

Comment: @CW0007007 The HIG states: "Think twice before preventing your application from running in all orientations. People expect to use your app in different orientations, and it’s best when you can fulfill that expectation. iPad users, in particular, expect to use your app in whichever orientation they’re currently holding their device." It says that iPad apps should only support one orientation if it is absolutely necessary. When the store first launched they were rejecting apps for this (I was rejected for only supporting landscape).

Comment: @kmcgrady Yeah I'm aware that you're supposed to but I was just pointing out that the app won't get rejected. :-)

Comment: @CW0007007 It still might, imo it isn't worth the risk. Like I said, I was rejected for not supporting all orientations. It's also generally better for the UX so worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is old and you say you fixed it, yet it is still marked as unanswered by StackOverflow.

I will add to the discussion that a view controller should only be doing things to its own view.  Anything you need to add, push, remove etc should be done from there.  The view controller should not be doing things to the window.  Good abstractions should focus on what is under them.